# Powershell check file type

Tags: powershell, file-type

I am working on a script that modifies images in a folder, for the most part, it is done I use `Get-ChildItem` with the directory.

So what I am currently doing is making a variable called

```
$fileExtension = [IO.Path]::GetExtension($files[$counter].Name)
```

with an if statement that is like:

```
if($fileExtension -eq '.png' or
    $fileExtensiono -eq '.jpg'. . . )
```

Is there a better way of doing this? I really want it to execute this function that modifies images if the file is an image, a folder could contain other items such as a zip which will crash the script if it picks up on it.

Comment: `If ('.png', '.jpg', ... -Contains $fileExtention) {...`

Comment: Now I did find an issue doing it that way, the thing that I am doing to these images is adding a number to the image itself. So Where I am doing Get-ChildItem I think I need it to just give me images. So I found that by using -Recusive and -Include @("*.png", etc.) works but if the folder has sub folders it crashes the script. How to I use the Get-ChildItem to just focus on the current directory only. Excluding Recursive the Include does not work.

Comment: I'd restrict to desired extensions firsthand when doing the `Get-ChildItem *|Where-Object Extension -in '.png','.jpg'` or `Get-ChildItem * -include '*.png','*.jpg'`

Comment: @LotPings - That was it! Where-Object was the solution ^-^ So if it has a file type other than common image file types it doesn't list them at all which allows the count to stay correct. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

try Something like this:

```
get-childitem 'c:\temp\*' -file -include '*.png', '*.jpg'
```